# tensorflow training endless when num epoch is set to None

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, training-data

I use the `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn`to generate input function, and it is something like this:

```
train_input = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'x': sst_train}, y=precip_train, shuffle=True, batch_size=100, num_epochs=None)
```

And the training process, I set up a for loop to control it. Here is the code:

```
for i in range(15):
est.train(input_fn=train_input, steps=20)
```

I think it should train 20*15 times in total, but it ends up with the endless loop. What's the problem here?

Answer (score -1):

"num_epochs: Integer, number of epochs to iterate over data. If `None` will run forever.". You can see this in api comment of `numpy_input_fn` function.

Comment: This shouldn't matter though if the number of steps is set in `estimator.train`.

Comment: Yes I think so. When the number of steps is set in train function, it should not run forever.